# javascript patterns for conditional loading of objects

Tags: javascript

We have made this decision to write all our java script in defintive module pattern. Using IIFE we are creating the modules for each individual page in the application.

We are bundling all the java script files. And the challenge is all the java script modules is available in all the pages. Is there any standard where I can conditionally load the required module whenever it is required.

Thank you

Comment: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Agree with requirejs. The two common specifications for doing this are CommonJS and AMD. The ECMA 6 specification has a built in module pattern but is not supported by many browsers currently. [Here's a good rundown on all 3 methods](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)